# Secur32Util.getUserNameEx replacement

Tags: java, winapi, single-sign-on, kerberos, jna

I have a case where a Java application uses Secur32Util.getUserNameEx from jna to obtain the username in a format for a single-sign-on. There are some machines where this function call is executing for a few minutes. I was not able to figure out why that is yet. But in the meantime, I would like to ask if there is a replacement that can be used to substitute that call.

To start the discussion, I have already tested that NTSystem#getName() and NTSystem#getDomain() return immediately on the machine that is stuck on executing Secur32Util.getUserNameEx. Are those functions interchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a corresponding C++ application that executed without delay. But, it turned out that my application was using JNA version 3.3 and when I updated to the current version it does not have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replay this problem in plain C?
What you can try is to call [`AqcuireCredentialsHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for SPNEGO or Kerberos and [query that object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the username (`SECPKG_CRED_ATTR_NAMES`). That will give you the very same result.